# In swift is is possible to separate set, get, willSet, and willGet from the declaration of the property?

Tags: properties, swift

I will start by showing you some properties from a project I'm working on...

```
/**  Properties  **/
var coordinates: Coordinates

var text: NSString = "" {
didSet {
    self.needsDisplay = true
}
}

var boxViewGroup: GridBoxViewGroup

var isLocked: Bool = false {
willSet {
    if isSelected || !newValue {
        boxViewGroup.selectedBox = nil
    }
}
}
var isSelected: Bool {
get {
    if boxViewGroup.selectedBox {
        return boxViewGroup.selectedBox === self
    }
    else {return false}
}
}

var invertedFrame: NSRect {
get {
    return NSRect(x: frame.origin.x,
                  y: superview.bounds.height - frame.origin.y,
              width: bounds.size.width,
             height: bounds.size.height)
}

set {

    self.frame = NSRect(x: newValue.origin.x,
                        y: superview.bounds.height - newValue.origin.y - newValue.height,
                    width: newValue.width,
                   height: newValue.height)
}
}
```

That looks a little messy right.  So my question is is it possible to put get, set, willGet, and willSet methods in a separate place so that my property declarations can look like this...

```
var coordinates: Coordinates
var boxViewGroup: GridBoxViewGroup
var isSelected: Bool
var invertedFrame: NSRect
```

See like this I can actually tell what properties there are.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by spiting in into 2 classes. You can override property declaration in subclass and add Property Observers

```
class DataA {
  var coordinates: Coordinates
  var boxViewGroup: GridBoxViewGroup
  var isSelected: Bool
  var invertedFrame: NSRect
}

class A : DataA {
  override var coordinates: Coordinates {
  didSet {
    //add code
  }
  willSet(newValue) {
    //add code 
  }
  } 
}
```

Read more about [Property Overriding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-XID_296) in apple documentation